# Missing image instead of imagepng

Tags: php

I have a problem.
That code should generate text to a image and showing this on the page, but doesn't work. That showing the missing image icon. Code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM imiona");
$stmt -> execute();

while($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $japan = $row['imie_japan'];
    $polish = $row['imie_polish'];
    
    echo "<b>".$polish."</b><br>";
    echo $japan."<br>";
    
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $fontsize = 40;
    $fonttype = 'ARIAL.TTF';
    $width  = imagefontwidth($fontsize) * strlen($japan);
    $height = imagefontheight($fontsize);
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    $white = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
    imagefill($image,0,0,$white);
    imagettftext($image,$fontsize,0,0,0,$black,$fonttype,$japan);
    imagepng ($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
    echo "<br>"; }
```

Comment: You have a loop, and you're sending the header in each loop? That won't do it. The image shouldn't output any HTML elements rather than the image content. Create a separate file for mapping out the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing only an image, you are echo'ing out multiple strings like `<b>".$polish."</b><br>";` and `$japan."<br>";` and then a `<br>` tag at the end.

Remove all that... That is causing the image itself to break as you cannot echo out random strings before and after an encoded image.